# How to set maximum x-axis value for HorizontalBarChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am working with the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library and I am trying to produce a Horizontal Bar Chart with only one item in the data set. The issue I am running into is setting the max value for the x-axis. I would like to say the max X value is 1000 and if the value in the data set is 500 then the bar chart would only go 1/2 way across the screen. My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to set the max value of the x axis for the Horizontal Bar Chart in the MPAndroidChart library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is kind of misleading, but for the `HorizontalBarChart`, this needs to be set via the y-axis :-)

Here is the [full documentation of the YAxis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis).

Check out the `setAxisMaxValue(float max)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is a great library. Is there any way to reduce the space around the chart. It doesn't seem like adjusting the padding or margins have any impact.